# How can I use one service to update both the parent and child scope in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, angularjs-scope

I am trying to implement services more in my code and would like to use only one service that updates data in both `ParentCtrl` and `ChildCtrl` at the same time.

I have read that services are singletons and do not take `$scope`. I have also read that when updating the `ParentCtrl` from `ChildCtrl`, the action is initiated from within the child and not the other way around (i.e. the parent does not have access to the child's scope but the child's scope can modify properties contained in the parent scope).

I have tried using both `$parent` as well as targeting an object in the parent with no success.

My HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    <!--Parent Scope: {{data}} option 1: doesn't work-->
    Parent Scope: {{data.key}}  <!-- option 2: doesn't work -->
    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl as vm">
      Child Scope: {{vm.data}}
      <button ng-click="vm.update(vm.child)">Click Me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp')
.controller('ParentCtrl', function($scope) {
    //$scope.data = '';
  $scope.data = { key: '' };
})

angular.module('myApp')
.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
  vm = this;
  vm.child = "Henry, Jr."
  vm.update = myService.alertFn;
  //$scope.$parent.data = vm.update;  // option 1: doesn't work
  $scope.data.key = vm.update;  // option 2: doesn't work
})

angular.module('myApp')
.service('myService', function() {
    return {
    alertFn: function(data) {
        vm.data = data;
    }
  }
})
```

I suspect that one of the problems is that the child controller's `vm.data` is empty when Angular uses it to modify the parent but I cannot figure out how to get the child controller to update the parent after `vm.data` is populated.

How can I use one service to update both the parent and child scope?

For reference, see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samurai_jane/uywxk75x/).

Answer (score 0):

Child controllers can communicate with their parents, but not the other way around, at least not directly. There are a lot of pitfalls to be aware of when you are trying to manage communication between components. This is a very good article to checkout the basics https://rclayton.silvrback.com/parent-child-controller-communication. Another good resource to check out is information about broadcasting. https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/

```
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
      Parent Scope: {{data}}
      <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl as vm">
        Child Scope: {{vm.data}}
        <button ng-click="vm.update(vm.child)">Click Me</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The JS

```
  angular.module('myApp', []);

  angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('ParentCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.data = '';
  })

  angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope, myService) {
    vm = this;
    vm.child = "Henry, Jr."
    vm.update = (data) => {
      myService.alertFn(data);
      //Here you have access to `$parent` you can use the results from
      //the service call too if you want.
      $scope.$parent.data = data;
    };
  })

  angular.module('myApp')
  .service('myService', function() {
      return {
      alertFn: function(data) {
          vm.data = data;
      }
    }
  })
```

Works for me. Hopefully this shines some light.

Comment: Nice one but this represents like `$scope.$parent.data=vm.child`. Direct assignment. It doesn't mean that both controllers sharing data through service.

Comment: Is there a reason behind `$rootScope`? It seems to work without it but was curious if it needs to be there for some reason. See https://jsfiddle.net/samurai_jane/uywxk75x/3/

Comment: You are absolutely right @samurai_jane type, will edit. Thank you